# Why is the first If 'is Not' statement not working?

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement

I am trying to valdate a drop down by checking to see that something other than the first option ("Choose one") is skipped

Logic: Is it true that the value is NOT "choose"?  If so, return true (submit the form). I believe the logic requires me to test to see if the value is NOT the first option. My code seems correct, but I guess I am not doing the "!" operator correctly.

I have tried these versions of "If val is NOT string; but they didn't work.

```
 if(val !== 'choose') 
 if(val != 'choose')
```

// Code example below

```
<form onsubmit="return validatedMenu()">
    <select id="dropDown">
        <option value="choose">Choose one...</option>
        <option value="1">test1</option>
        <option value="2">test2</option>
        <option value="3">test3</option>
    </select>  
    <input type="submit" value="select" />
</form>
<div>message here: <span id="mySpan"></span></div>

    function validatedMenu() {
        var dd = document.getElementById("dropDown");
        var val = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value;
        var txt = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].text;

        if(val != 'choose') {
            document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = "You must make a selection.";
        }
        else { 
            document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = "Success! You chose " + txt;
            return false;
            }
    return true;
    }
```

Comment: I believe the logic requires me to test to if the value is NOT the first option. My code seems correct, but I guess I am not doing the "!" operator correctly.

Comment: It just makes no sense... You should check if it IS the first option to alert that "you must make a selection"... If is not the first one, he already made a valid selection, don't you think?

Answer (score 3):

You just have your logic flipped backwards. If `val != 'choose'`, that means that the user HAS made a selection. However, in that if statement you're running the logic for when they have not. You just need to flip the contents of your if/else:

```
function validatedMenu() {
    var dd = document.getElementById("dropDown");
    var val = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value;
    var txt = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].text;

    if(val != 'choose') {
        document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = "Success! You chose " + txt;
        return true;
    }
    else { 
        document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = "You must make a selection.";
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, if you for some reason wanted to have the success condition as the else and the failure condition as the if,  you'll just need to reverse what you're evaluating in the if(), so that selecting the first option will cause it to be true:

```
function validatedMenu() {
    var dd = document.getElementById("dropDown");
    var val = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value;
    var txt = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].text;

    if(val == 'choose') {
        document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = "You must make a selection.";
        return false;
    }
    else { 
        document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = "Success! You chose " + txt;
        }
return true;
}
```

Comment: sphanley- It didn't work when I tried it. Desired logic: If the user choose the first option, return false, with the message, "You must make a selection." Otherwise, Else, return true, with message, "Success..."

Comment: That's what the snipped I posted will do. If the user chose the first option, the if will fail, the else will run, and they will hit the return false. If they chose anything other than the first option, they will enter the if statement and  return true with success.

Comment: That said, I posted a second way to fix it which leaves the failure scenario in the if. Either one should do what you're asking for.

Comment: sphanley - Thank you. I took your code and removed your 'return false' on the else statement and put the 'return false' on the first IF statement, and that worked. :)

Comment: Ah, yes, that was a mistake. I'd appreciate you accepting the answer if it solved your problem!